# Typescript - How to use a union of keys as a index?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I am receiving a input that can represent two different objects with different properties and I have to update my list with the input. To use the input fields as a index I am trying to do a Union type of the keys of the interfaces. But I am still not being able to use as a index signature.

```
interface Foo{
  featureFOO1: boolean
  featureFOO2: boolean
}
interface Bar{
  featureBAR1: boolean
  featureBAR2: boolean
}

interface T {
  foo: Foo;
  bar: Bar
}

const input = {
  type: 'foo', // could be bar;
  featureName: 'featureFOO1', // coud be featureBAR1
  value: false
}

const list = {
  foo: {
    featureFOO1: true,
    featureFOO2: false
  },
  bar: {
    featureBAR1: true,
    featureBAR2: false
  }
}
type Union = Foo | Bar
type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T: never
type AvailableKeys = KeysOfUnion<Union>

list[input.type as keyof T][input.featureName as AvailableKeys] = input.value
```

Error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'AvailableKeys' can't be used to index type '{ featureFOO1: boolean; featureFOO2: boolean; } | { featureBAR1: boolean; featureBAR2: boolean; }'.
Property 'featureFOO1' does not exist on type '{ featureFOO1: boolean; featureFOO2: boolean; } | { featureBAR1: boolean; featureBAR2: boolean; }'.(7053)

Answer (score 0):

This look like the perfect use case for a discriminated union.

```
type TInput =
  | {
      type: "bar";
      featureName: keyof Bar;
      value: boolean;
    }
  | {
      type: "foo";
      featureName: keyof Foo;
      value: boolean;
    };

const input: TInput = {
  type: "foo",
  featureName: "featureFOO1",
  value: false,
};

const list = {
  foo: {
    featureFOO1: true,
    featureFOO2: false,
  },
  bar: {
    featureBAR1: true,
    featureBAR2: false,
  },
};

// TS knows that featureName must be a FOO because type is "foo"
list[input.type][input.featureName] = input.value;
```